# Why does this boolean expression in sympy evaluate to false: (~a&b)|(a&~b)==a^b?

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, sympy, algebra

I've been working with [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to simplify and evaluate boolean expressions. I have encountered this simple case, the mentioned expression in the question, which doesn't evaluate to `True`. Sample code is as follows:

```
from sympy import *
a, b=symbols('a b')
(~a&b)|(a&~b)==a^b
```

evaluates to False.

Comment: See [sympy's gotchas](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs). Also in the [faq](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Faq#why-does-sympy-say-that-two-equal-expressions-are-unequal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the tutorial:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs

The two expressions you have are not structurally equal:

```
In [2]: (~a&b)|(a&~b)                                                                                                  
Out[2]: (a ∧ ¬b) ∨ (b ∧ ¬a)

In [3]: a^b                                                                                                            
Out[3]: a ⊻ b
```

Therefore they will not compare equal with `==`.

You can simplify them to compare them:

```
In [9]: simplify_logic((~a&b)|(a&~b))                                                                                  
Out[9]: (a ∧ ¬b) ∨ (b ∧ ¬a)

In [10]: simplify_logic(a^b)                                                                                           
Out[10]: (a ∧ ¬b) ∨ (b ∧ ¬a)

In [11]: simplify_logic((~a&b)|(a&~b)) == simplify_logic(a^b)                                                          
Out[11]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [faq](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Faq#why-does-sympy-say-that-two-equal-expressions-are-unequal) and in [sympy's gotchas](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs), the double equal sign only tests for exact equality.

To test whether two boolean expressions are equivallent, use [`Equivalent(lhs, rhs)`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#sympy.logic.boolalg.Equivalent) followed by `simplify()`.

```
from sympy import symbols, Equivalent

a, b = symbols('a b')
print(Equivalent(((~a & b) | (a & ~b)), (a ^ b)).simplify())
```

Prints `True`.